# Implementing steepest descent algorithm, variable step size

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, numerical-methods, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement steepest descent algorithm in programming languages (C/C++/fortran).

For example minimization of f(x1,x2) = x1^3 + x2^3 - 2*x1*x2

1. Estimate starting design point x0, iteration counter k0, convergence parameter tolerence = 0.1. 
   Say this staring point is (1,0)
2. Compute gradient of f(x1,x2) at the current point x(k) as grad(f). I will use numerical differentiation here.

   d/dx1 (f) = lim (h->0) (f(x1+h,x2) - f(x1,x2) )/h

   This is grad(f)=(3*x1^2 - 2*x2, 3*x2^2 - 2*x1)

   grad(f) at (0,1) is  c0 = (3,-2)
3. since L2 norm of c0 > tolerence, we proceed for next step
4. direction d0 = -c0 = (-3,2)
5. Calculate step size a. Minimize f(a) = f(x0 + a*d0) = (1-3a,2a) = (1-3a)^3 + (2a)^3 - 2*(1-3a)*(2a). I am not keeping constant step size.
6. update: new[x1,x2] = old[x1,x2]x + a*d0.

I do not understand how to do step 5. 
I have a 1D minimization program with bisection method, and it looks like:

```
program main()
    ...
    ...
    define upper, lower interval
    call function value
    ...calculations
    ...
    ...


function value (input x1in) (output xout)
    ...function is x^4 - 2x^2 + x + 10 
    xout = (xin)^4 - 2*(xin)^2 + (xin) + 10
```

In this case, looking at step 5, I cannot pass symbolic a.
Any ideas how to implement the algorithm in programming language, especially step 5? Please suggest if there is altogether different way to program this. I have seen many programs with constant step size, but I want to compute it at every step. This algorithm can be easy to implement in MATLAB ot python sympy using symbolics, but I do not want to use symbolics. 
Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate a, how to store it for use in every iteration or how to pass it as a parameter to the function? In order to help you, we need to see the actual relevant portion of code that you use.

Comment: The code to calculate 1D optimum value has around 200 lines and several included other files. It may not be a good idea to give it here. So I gave a rough template how that code works.

Comment: @o_weisman  Basically, I have a function code that takes in variable, plugs in in the equation and gives out the result of function. In my case of gradient method algo, there is this symbolic variable  `a` that I don't know how to handle.

Comment: If you know how to mathematically compute a, just compute it and pass it as another parameter to the function. If you don't, you should probably ask on a different forum that deals with math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If C++ is an option, you can take advantage of [functors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses) and [lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11).

Let's consider a function we want to minimize, for example y = x<sup>2</sup> - x + 2. It can be represented as a function object, which is a class with an overloaded `operator()`:

```
struct MyFunc {
    double operator()( double x ) const {
        return  x * x - x + 2.0;
    }
};
```

Now we can declare an object of this type, use it like a function and pass it to other templated function as a templated parameter.

```
// given this templated function:
template < typename F >
void tabulate_function( F func, double a, double b, int steps ) {
    //  the functor     ^^^^^^  is passed to the templated function
    double step = (b - a) / (steps - 1);

    std::cout << "    x          f(x)\n------------------------\n";
    for ( int i = 0; i < steps; ++i ) {
        double x = a + i * step,
               fx = func(x);
        //          ^^^^^^^ call the operator() of the functor
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setw(8) << std::setprecision(3) << x
                  << std::scientific << std::setw(16) << std::setprecision(5)
                  << fx << '\n';
    }   
}

// we can use the previous functor like this:
MyFunc example;
tabulate_function(example, 0.0, 2.0, 21);
```

OP's function can be implemented (given an helper class to represent 2D points) in a similar way:

```
struct MyFuncVec {
    double operator()( const Point &p ) const {
        return p.x * p.x * p.x  +  p.y * p.y * p.y  -  2.0 * p.x * p.y;
    }
};
```

The gradient of that function can be represented (given a class which implement a 2D vector) by:

```
struct MyFuncGradient {
    Vector operator()( const Point &p ) {
        return Vector(3.0 * p.x * p.x  -  2.0 * p.y, 3.0 * p.y * p.y  -  2.0 * p.x);
    }
};
```

Now, the fifth step of OP question requests to minimize the first function along the direction of the gradient using a monodimensional optimization algorithm which requires a monodimensional function to be passed. We can solve this issue using a lambda:

```
    MyFuncVec funcOP;
    MyFuncGradient grad_funcOP; 
    Point p0(0.2, 0.8);
    Vector g = grad_funcOP(p0);

    // use a lambda to transform the OP function to 1D
    auto sliced_func = [&funcOP, &p0, &g] ( double t ) -> double {
        // those variables ^^^ ^^^ ^^ are captured and used
        return funcOP(p0 - t * g);
    };

    tabulate_function(sliced_func, 0, 0.5, 21);
```

Live example [HERE](https://ideone.com/Lj986M).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. which compiler did you use for your 'live example'? I got several compile time errors with gcc.

Comment: @de23edced ideone.com should use g++ too. Have you tried setting the option `-std=c++0x` at command line? Lambdas are a C++11 feature.